# CSS Media Query only works on browser resize (Edge)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have a website kryptobank.co.uk that uses media queries for responsiveness. It's sort of like a news article website. Not even developed yet and just has fake data and writing. The design works perfectly fine on the edge browser. When i resize the window i can see the flex box properties come into effect. However, that's the only browser it works on. When i resize chrome on my desktop or use the samsung browser on my phone it doesn't work. It applies the media queries properties even when the size hasn't even reached 769px which i set it be. I only have one css style sheet called index.css. It's a mess but this is how it looks

```
/* ================================= 
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ---- Navigation ---- */
.main-header {
  background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.name, .main-nav {
        text-align: center;
}

.name {
    text-shadow: 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */
.price-card{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;

}

.price-card p {
  margin-top: -15px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.price-card span{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 300px;
}

.intro-heading{
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.price {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.top-three {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
}

.title h1, 
.title span,
.title a{
    color: white;
    background-color: #000000;
    display: inline;
}

.list h1, 
.list span {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline;
}
.primary{
    height: 390px;
    width: 99%;
    margin: 7px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
    border-top: 10px solid firebrick;
}

.list{
    height: 390px;
    width: 99%;
    margin: 7px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
    margin: 5px 5px;
    border-top: 10px solid firebrick;
}

.back-image{
    height: 390px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 7px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
    border-top: 10px solid #ffa949;
}
.back-image h1, 
.back-image span {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline;
}
.content{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    max-width: 900px;

}
.content p {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 500;
}

h2 span {
    font-size: 12px;
}
/* ---- Page Elements ---- */

a:link    {
  /* Applies to all unvisited links */
  text-decoration:  none;
  font-weight:      bold;
  } 
a:visited {
  /* Applies to all visited links */
  text-decoration:  none;
  font-weight:      bold;
  } 
a:hover   {
  /* Applies to links under the pointer */
  text-decoration:  underline;
  font-weight:      bold;

  } 
a:active  {
  /* Applies to activated links */
  text-decoration:  underline;
  font-weight:      bold;

  } 


/* ================================= 
  Flexbox
==================================== */


@media only screen and (min-width: 769px){
    .top-three {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .name, .main-nav {
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul li {
        display: inline;
        background-color: #000;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    li a {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .latest-10,
    .all{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .list{
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-basis: 300px;
    }

}
```

And this is the HTML page

```
<body>
            <header>
                <h1 class="name"><a href="/">KYPTOBANK</a></h1>
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">01 - HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/articles/">02 - NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">03 - CURRENCY EXCHNAGE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">04 - ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">05 - CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </header><!--/.main-header-->

            <div id="root"></div>

    <h2 class="intro-heading">Top Three</h2>
    <div class="top-three">

      <div class="primary" style="background-image:url(http://themarketmogul.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/india_money_1498129850.jpg)">
        <div class="title">
          <h1> <a href="/articles/1/">How India&#39;s Demonstartion has change Paytm&#39;s Fortunes</a></h1>
          <br>
          <span>Emerging Economy</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="primary" style="background-image:url(http://themarketmogul.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/pexels-photo-136721.jpeg)">
        <div class="title">
          <h1> <a href="/articles/2/">Hear The Drums Echoing Tonight? The Relentless March Of Online Money Transfers In Africa</a></h1>
          <br>
          <span>Africa Emerging</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="primary" style="background-image:url(http://themarketmogul.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/trading_1498053453.jpg)">
        <div class="title">
          <h1> <a href="/articles/3/">Raise The Stakes: Learn How To Improve The Win/Loss Ratio</a></h1>
          <br>
          <span>London Rising</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <h2 class="intro-heading">Latest Articles</h2>
      <div class="latest-10">

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/4/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/5/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/6/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/7/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/8/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

      <div class="list" style="background-image:linear-gradient(#ffa949, transparent 90%),linear-gradient(to top, #fff, transparent),url(https://media.coindesk.com/uploads/2017/06/shutterstock_307175279.jpg);">
        <h1> <a href="/articles/9/">GDAX Exchange to Reimburse Traders After Ether Flash Crash</a></h1>
          <br>
        <span>Market Collapse</span>
      </div>

    </div>
```

You can view the website for yourself.

Comment: Is that the correct URL? I get a 'bad request 400:

Comment: Yep this is the correct url

Comment: It's working fine for me right now unless you wrote it wrong. The website is like 10% done so will likely have 400 or 500 errors etc.

Comment: Found the problem. Just write kryptobank.co.uk without the www at the beginning. It was a bad URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's resizing fine on my chrome browser, however on a device, I think you'll need to add a viewport meta tag so that the site is aware of the device it's being viewed on:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in Chrome as of 6/27/17. Try adding a

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

a guide can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)